# Allow EE Code add-on: work also with email template?

Tags: email

https://expressionengine.com/add-ons/allow-ee-code

Besides channel entries, can this add in used also fir system email template?

Answer (score 0):

The system message templates (to generate error messages and system emails) use a different approach to rendering and these do not currently behave much like normal templates - for example there are only a few built-in tags that work within them, and third-party add-ons are not supported.

Until such times as EE changes this, if you want to have more complete control over your system messages you should check out **[Custom System Messages](https://boldminded.com/add-ons/csm)** an ad-on which might give you what you are looking for.

HTH

Comment: Interesting. Could you clarify if it works with EE 5.x? If I install this add-on I’m allowed to customize only a couple of system emails without the needs to customize all emails? I’m in need to send system emails in different language depending a parameter in the member profile

Comment: Using Custom System.Message, works perfectly with EE 5.x.

Comment: As far as I know CSM lets you replace the existing templates with any valid EE template - which would suggest you could include a conditional to switch the email around based on language.  If multi-language is important, you might even be able to link it up with Publisher (https://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher) from the same source - a very powerful mult-lingual package for EE.

Comment: CSM add-on doesn’t work with email template that is what I’m looking for.